# Dynamic Nested Dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, nested

I need to access a dictionary in Python depending on a list. Example:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Then the dictionary accessing should be:

```
d['A']['B']['C']
```

The list can be of any depth/elements.

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a example case of real input and expected output.

Comment: What do you want to do if one of the keys is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a function that iterates through the list:

```
d = {}
d['A'] = {}
d['A']['B'] = {}
d['A']['B']['C'] = 'value'
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def get_value(d, lst):
    for elem in lst:
        d = d[elem]
    return d

print get_value(d, lst)  # outputs 'value'
```

Comment: Why did you introduce a new variable instead of just rebinding `d`?

Comment: You're right, I edited the answer!

Comment: Is there a way to create a nested dictionary using the list? So if `lst = [ 'A', 'B', 'C']` then the dict created would be `d['A']['B']['C'] = {}`

Comment: @John. Why not try something yourself, even if it is just Googling? Your original question was closed as a duplicate, and I am pretty sure this new one is too.

Answer (score 2):

One may also use the `eval` function applied to a string generated from the list:

```
eval('d[\''+'\'][\''.join(lst)+'\']')
```

here `'\'][\''` is a delimiter

Comment: it has past the test

Comment: My mistake. I did not read carefully. Downvote removed even though this is still bad advice.

Comment: what may be a better advice considering that we know nothing about the list and dictionary and how do they match together

Comment: Iterating through the list so you can actually do some checks?